# Offset Polar Bar Radial Origin, python Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I am generating a WindRose using Plotly Express, and was wondering if it is possible to offset the start point for the radial.

What I would like to achieve would be to show 0-2 MPH wind as a circle showing calm, as in figure 2.

Not sure if its possible or how to do so, any help would be appreciated.

[WindRose generated using Plotly Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64MLa.png)

[Windrose that I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQi0.png)

```
fig = px.bar_polar(df, r= "Frequency", theta="Direction",
                   color="Strength", template="none",
                   labels={"Strength": "Wind Speed in MPH"}
                   )

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="top",
    y=-0.1,
    xanchor="center",
    x=0.5),
    polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, ticks='', linewidth=0)
    )
)
fig.show()
```

```html
Direction,Strength,Frequency
N,0-2,1.45
N,2-5,0.4
N,5-7,
N,7-10,
N,10-15,
N,15-20,
NNE,0-2,0.53
NNE,2-5,0.53
NNE,5-7,
NNE,7-10,
NNE,10-15,
NNE,15-20,
NE,0-2,1.06
NE,2-5,
NE,5-7,
NE,7-10,
NE,10-15,
NE,15-20,
ENE,0-2,0.79
ENE,2-5,0.4
ENE,5-7,
ENE,7-10,
ENE,10-15,
ENE,15-20,
E,0-2,1.32
E,2-5,
E,5-7,
E,7-10,
E,10-15,
E,15-20,
ESE,0-2,1.19
ESE,2-5,0.26
ESE,5-7,
ESE,7-10,
ESE,10-15,
ESE,15-20,
SE,0-2,1.72
SE,2-5,1.19
SE,5-7,0.4
SE,7-10,0.13
SE,10-15,
SE,15-20,
SSE,0-2,1.19
SSE,2-5,3.04
SSE,5-7,1.98
SSE,7-10,0.4
SSE,10-15,
SSE,15-20,
S,0-2,1.06
S,2-5,3.17
S,5-7,1.19
S,7-10,
S,10-15,
S,15-20,
SSW,0-2,0.13
SSW,2-5,2.11
SSW,5-7,0.4
SSW,7-10,
SSW,10-15,
SSW,15-20,
SW,0-2,0.79
SW,2-5,0.92
SW,5-7,0.53
SW,7-10,
SW,10-15,
SW,15-20,
WSW,0-2,0.79
WSW,2-5,1.19
WSW,5-7,0.26
WSW,7-10,
WSW,10-15,
WSW,15-20,
W,0-2,0.92
W,2-5,3.83
W,5-7,2.64
W,7-10,0.4
W,10-15,
W,15-20,
WNW,0-2,3.3
WNW,2-5,7.53
WNW,5-7,9.64
WNW,7-10,4.62
WNW,10-15,0.79
WNW,15-20,
NW,0-2,1.72
NW,2-5,10.04
NW,5-7,11.1
NW,7-10,7.4
NW,10-15,1.06
NW,15-20,
NNW,0-2,1.85
NNW,2-5,1.85
NNW,5-7,0.79
NNW,7-10,
NNW,10-15,
NNW,15-20,
```

Comment: Can you share the dataframe you are working with, or a sample dataframe similar to yours? Otherwise your plots are not reproducible.

Comment: Hi Derek,

I added my data.
This is the data that gets passed to the plotting function.
I wasn't able to add a CSV file therefore added as an html after the code.

Comment: Thanks! This will be really helpful to anyone who wants to try to tackle your issue, myself included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to adjust the starting radius value for a `bar_polar` plot in Plotly, your best bet is to try to find some workaround.

This is admittedly a *very* hacky solution, but to ensure that the chart isn't too close to the origin, we can create a `New_Frequency` column that simply adds an arbitrary value to the `Frequency` column. I chose 30. Note that doing this will distort the relative distance between the bars (if this is a problem, then the solution will need to be modified somehow).

Then we set the parameter `r` in the bar_polar method to this new column, and modify the hover data so that it displays the original Frequency column.

[image]

Now we can draw a circle with the text "Calm" that covers the inner bars corresponding to values of `0-2 MPH`. When adding a shape, you need to specify Cartesian coordinates despite the fact that this is a polar coordinate plot. After some trial and error, it seems that x=0.5, y=0.5 is the center of the bar_polar plot, and that a circle going from x0=0.4, y0=0.4, x1=0.6, y1=0.6 covers the inner bars. I don't know if there's documentation for this.

If you're only after the image, then hopefully it looks pretty good. Note that toggling the different wind speeds in the legend will distort the plot, and the circle won't cover the inner bars anymore, so you lose some of the interactiveness of the plot.

[image]

I have included the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv("windrose.csv")

## this adds 30 to all frequencies, so 0-2 becomes 30-32
df["New_Frequency"] = df["Frequency"] + 30

fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="New_Frequency", theta="Direction",
                   color="Strength", template="none",
                   labels={"Strength": "Wind Speed in MPH"},
                   hover_data={"Strength":True, "New_Frequency":False, "Frequency":True ,"Direction":True}
                   )

fig.add_shape(
    type="circle",
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            x0=0.4,
            y0=0.4,
            x1=0.6,
            y1=0.6,
            line_color="Black",
            fillcolor="White",
            # text="Calm"
)

fig.add_annotation( # add a text callout with arrow
    text="Calm", x=0.5, y=0.5, showarrow=False
)

fig.update_layout(width=800, height=800)
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="top",
    y=-0.1,
    xanchor="center",
    x=0.5),
    polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, ticks='', linewidth=0)
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helps and I apologize for the late response, was under mandatory evacuation due to the fires. I had another question, if you had the time. I was wondering if it was possible to show percentages in the legend ? for instance where it shows 0-2, I would want it to show 0-2 x%

Comment: I am glad to hear my answer was helpful, I will look into displaying `%` in the legend. You can consider trying to change the format of your data, or literally add the symbol to the legend text. I hope you and your family are safe during these tough times- I am in Norcal so we're experiencing the fallout and dark skies, but thankfully the fires haven't spread here just yet

Comment: Thank you, hope all is well with you and your family. I had a question, I am trying to add an extra box(annotation) with text on the side of the chart, like the legend, to display wind speed percentage, I am able to add the annotation on the side, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fill out the annotation from a data frame. The data frame has 5 rows and two columns that I would like to display next to the plot, is there a way to possibly do that?
edit: in simpler terms, I want to display a table next to the plot which gets its data from a data frame.

Comment: I can look into it, but I think that's definitely worth asking as a separate question!

Comment: Thank you, I will ask that as a new question. Btw I was able to find another work around for adding a circle for calm in the middle. I used "hole" in update_layout, I will add my code for that as an answer once I get it working properly. I appreciate all your help. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah that's a good workaround as well! No problem, and I am glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution for adding a circle in the middle of a polar bar chart, by using "hole" in the update_layout. Code is attached below:

```
fig2 = px.bar_polar(df, r="Frequency", theta="Direction",
                    color="Strength", template="none",
                    labels={"Strength": "Wind Speed <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; in MPH:"
                            }
                    )

fig2.add_annotation(
    text="Calm<br>" + " " + percent + "%", x=0.5, y=0.5, showarrow=False
)

fig2.add_annotation(
    text="Calm Values are for <br> Wind Speed <2.0 MPH <br />", x=0.93, y=-0.13, showarrow=False
)

fig2.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="middle",  
    y=-0.1,
    xanchor="center",
    x=0.5,
    font=dict(
        size=14)),
    polar=dict(hole=0.1, radialaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, ticks='', linewidth=0)
               ),
    margin=dict(t=110),
    title=dict(
        text=title,
        xanchor='center',
        yanchor='top'
    )
)
```

output: [image: Wind Rose with Circle in Center]

Since 0-2 MPH is displayed as a circle in the middle, in my data frame I set the value of all 0-2 MPH to zero, this makes sure the 0-2 bins are not displayed.